# Need to find a good analogy

Tags: health-education, disorders, tourette-syndrome, public-awareness

I need to explain to someone that Tourette Syndrome is more than just tics.  I would like to do this with an analogy.  People at my son's school keep saying they haven't noticed any tics, and they have ignored what we've tried to explain about the other symptoms of this spectrum disorder.  The Tourette Association says that tics are just the tip of the iceberg, since there are many other conditions that are often associated with TS (comorbid) -- but these people don't seem to be able to take that in.

What would be a good analogy for this?  I need something that's really easy for everyone to relate to.

Comment: Still can't crack my skull open for that. Have you read Oliver Sacks: "An Anthropologist on Mars: Seven Paradoxical Tales"? The start of ch "A Surgeon’s Life" (about someone with TS) might help to refine the Q here. – Are they missing the whole picture, dismiss the diagnosis, maltreat the child or you? There seems to be a problem, but I do not grasp it, yet.

Comment: @LangLangC - Sure, they've made my life miserable, but that's not the point.  They make the child's life miserable.  They send him to the back of the room, to the hall, to the principal's office, they scold him, they humiliate him.  They do not understand his condition.  Yes, Sacks' writing and videos about Tourette have been very helpful for me.  School personnel have not been willing to spend much time learning about Tourette -- they're not going to give Sacks' work the time of day.  Does that help you understand my request for an analogy?  Let me know if I can provide further clarification.